# failing to start docker engine open //./pipe/docker_engine

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10

I'm receiving the following error in docker on windows 10 laptop.
I've try to reinstall and restart but nothing helps.

The docker service is running OK but what i understand that i have a problem with the docker daemon (from what i read)
[image]

The whole issue started when i run the 2 commands:

```
net stop com.docker.service
net start com.docker.service
```

from there on i keep getting the error below and cannot solve it.

> C:\Users\xxxx>docker images error during connect: Get
>   http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.30/images/json: open
>   //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In
>   the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be
>   run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker
>   daemon is not running.

anyone succeed to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

> docker client must be run elevated to connect

This indicates that you do not have enough permissions. Try starting the terminal as administrator.

Comment: i'm with elevated

Answer (score 0):

I run Docker remotely as a non admin user.

1. For this the user running docker should have full permission to location where Docker is installed.
2. User should be part of docker_users group
3. docker daemon runs on port 2375 by default. Try to whitelist this port. Allow incoming connections to 2375 in Windows Firewall settings

Restart your docker daemon and Docker service.

Restart the running Docker instance[Docker for Windows] if required. You do not have to reinstall.